# Is there any way to make someone choose the operation?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a dice roller bot for Discord and basically I want to make possible to someone choose what they want to do. If they want to add 6 with the dice result, if they want to half the dice result and things like that.
I made the code, and it can sum, but can't do other operations.

```
@client.command(aliases=['r', 'dado', 'dice'])
 async def roll(ctx, numero=20, conta='+', ficha=0):
     rolagem = random.randint(1,int(numero))
     total = (int(rolagem) + int(ficha))
     await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}  \n**Resultado**: D{numero} ({rolagem}) {conta} {ficha}\n**Total**: {total}')
```

Thats the code. In the total part, I want to use what they choose in the conta. Is there any way to do it? I already tried a lot, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `eval()`, you can use a if-elif-else conditional blocks.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['r', 'dado', 'dice'])
 async def roll(ctx, numero=20, conta='+', ficha=0):
     rolagem = random.randint(1,int(numero))
     if conta == '+':
         total = (int(rolagem) + int(ficha))
     elif conta == '-':
         total = (int(rolagem) + int(ficha))
     # keep on adding as needed
     await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}  \n**Resultado**: D{numero} ({rolagem}) {conta} {ficha}\n**Total**: {total}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your code then you are using total to represent the users transformation. This could be achieved with a `match case` statement.

```
match conta:
    case '+':
        total = rolagem + int(ficha)
    case '*':
        total = rolagem * int(ficha)
    etc. for other operators
```

Comment: `match`/`case` is new in python 3.10, which is not yet released.

Comment: Ty, helped me a lot! I'll use this in future updates.

Comment: For a current solution [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) has some options. elifs are probably fine here but can become unwieldy and are harder to maintain if a variables name changes for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be achived using `eval()` like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["r", "dado", "dice"])
async def roll(ctx, numero=20, conta="+6"):
    rolagem = random.randint(1, int(numero))
    total = eval(f"{rolagem}{conta}")
    await ctx.send(
        f"{ctx.author.mention}  \n**Resultado**: D{numero} ({rolagem}) {conta}\n**Total**: {total}"
    )
```

by using this method you can even do some complicated math with your rolled number. If you are afraid of code injection you can make a list of allowed characters and check if the `conta` contains something out of this list.

Comment: Try not to use eval since it is highly possible that you can exploit it.

Comment: I'll try to do the list of allowed. You just saved me, ty!!!